# How to use dynamic data in mailchimp newsletters

Tags: javascript, php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am working on LMS application,
Where I have dashboard data like "pending task, grades, number of courses
enrolled etc" and these data are dynamic.
I need to send these data to students(say 200) via mailchimp.
Can anyone tell me how to integrate it?

> Note : Dashboard is a php file..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Mailchimp API, by sending the data using `cURL` commands:

You can get some information [here](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/) and there is even a very good tutorial [here](https://rudrastyh.com/api/mailchimp-subscription.html). Typically, we want to see examples of what you have tried before we just go a head and code it for you, though.